# Find the secret message

Tags: cipher, visual

The word under secret means something. What does it mean? (Find the secret message.)

[image]

Comment: The puzzle is good (+1 from me), but the presentation could be a bit better. It actually turned me away from it at first glance. Maybe it *is* worth spending a bit more time on creating the images for puzzles...

Comment: It would be arguably easier for me to make "nicer looking" images but I like imagining the scenario of a "childish" image hanging on a popular wall where no one pays attention to it, yet it contains the secret to a treasure. I see your point though and will consider making some polished image puzzles in the future.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The solution is:

> gibberish

These were my steps to find the answer - first, I:

> Got the RGB ASCII values for every color.
>  These were, **For the word secret:**
>  31 41 59, 26 53 58, 97 93 23, 84 62 64, 33 83 27, 13 37 0
>  **For the text at the bottom:**
> 22 9 7 5 14 5 18 5 20 (Only the 'red' bit of the color had a value other than zero).

Then, by realizing that:

> The numbers for the top section correspond to the value of PI

And that:

> The numbers 22 9 7 5 14 5 18 5 20 when turned into letters, A=1, Z=26 correspond to VIGENERE(T)

You find that:

> That *vqqjtzxaw* decoded via the Vigenere cipher with a key of PI yields *gibberish*.

Comment: Wow that was fast, now I know I can make them less obvious. I was going to do something with the last letter (the 13 37 0 aren't pi) but thought it'd be getting too hard. I left the extra "T" though to "disguise" the cipher name.

Comment: 90 mins... that was relatively quick... +1!